# iOS autoLayout views not showing on screen?

Tags: ios, objective-c, autolayout

When I was using initWithFrame, everything was fine. But my supervisors advised that autoLayout is generally a better practice. So I tried adding 4 constraints to an imageView, and suddenly it won't show up on my screens when I run it on the simulator.

```
- (UIImageView *) titleImage
{
    if (!_titleImage){
        _titleImage =[[UIImageView alloc] init];
        _titleImage.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"Example.png"];

        [self.view addConstraint:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_titleImage
                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                toItem:self.view
                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTop
                multiplier:1.0
                constant:100]];
        [self.view addConstraint:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_titleImage
                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                toItem:self.view
                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeLeading
                multiplier:1.0
                constant:100]];
        [self.view addConstraint:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_titleImage
                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                toItem:self.view
                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeTrailing
                multiplier:1.0
                constant:-100]];
        [self.view addConstraint:
         [NSLayoutConstraint constraintWithItem:_titleImage
                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                relatedBy:NSLayoutRelationEqual
                toItem:self.view
                attribute:NSLayoutAttributeBottom
                multiplier:1.0
                constant:-100]];
    }
    return _titleImage;
}
```

And then in the loadView method I have...

```
[self.view addSubview:self.titleImage];
```

When I just used initWithFrame `x`, `y`, `width`, `height` it was working fine. I removed that line and added 4 constraints and now I can't get it to show up on my screen.

Comment: You need to add the constraints AFTER you addSubview

Comment: so I can't add constraints in my setter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. You should add `_titleImage` as a subview before you add constraints.
2. On any view you're using with AutoLayout, you must call :

   ```
   [_titleImage setTranslatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints:NO];
   ```